# Parsing JSON in Swift 3 (CLLocationCoordinate2D)

Tags: json, swift, google-places-api

I'm trying to parse a JSON link with the Google Places iOS API. When I print the coordinates, it appears as

> CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)

rather than the actual coordinates of the place. It may be, I think, a dictionary/object issue, but am lost for solutions.

Below is my JSON parsing code:

```
func parseJsonData(data: NSData) -> [GymGooglePlace] {

    do {

        typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]

        if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data) as? JSONDictionary, let gyms = parsedData["results"] as? [JSONDictionary] {

            for gym in gyms {

                var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
                var latitude:CLLocationDegrees!
                var longitude:CLLocationDegrees!

                var maxWidth:Int!
                var photoReference:String!
                let photoURL:String!

                if let geometry = gym["geometry"] as? [JSONDictionary] {

                    for result in geometry {

                        if let locations = result["location"] as? [JSONDictionary] {

                            for location in locations {

                                latitude = location["lat"] as! CLLocationDegrees!
                                longitude = location["lng"] as! CLLocationDegrees!

                                coordinate.latitude = latitude
                                coordinate.longitude = longitude
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if let photos = gym["photos"] as? [JSONDictionary] {

                    for photo in photos {

                        maxWidth = photo["width"] as! Int!
                        photoReference = photo["photo_reference"] as! String!
                    }
                }

                photoURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=\(maxWidth!)&photoreference=\(photoReference!)&key=\(googleAPIKey)"

                print(photoURL)
                print(coordinate)
                print("spacespacespacespacespacespacespacespacespace")
            }
        }



    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return gymGooglePlaces
}
```

Comment: What does your JSON look like? Have you made sure that you are getting actual lat and long values, i.e. that result["location"] actually contains some data?

Comment: To be honest, I used to parse JSON payload manually, so I didn't need to pull in any 3rd party lib. But now, I like some pods like ObjectMapper or SwiftyJson. So when your JSON payload structure changes, what you need to do is only change the keypath, instead of rewriting the parse method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for the keys `geometry` and `location` are dictionaries, please note the `{}`, array is `[]`

```
 if let geometry = gym["geometry"] as? JSONDictionary,
    let location = geometry["location"] as? JSONDictionary {
         coordinate.latitude = location["lat"] as! CLLocationDegrees
         coordinate.longitude = location["lng"] as! CLLocationDegrees
 }
```